# what should be used apart for COALESCE for better query optimization

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am not that good with SQL Server, but I take keen interest in learning it. I have written a query here below which gets the result by using a COALESCE. I tried to optmized the query as much as I can. Do we have anything good apart from COALESCE that can help in faster performance?

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT Account.AcctID, 
Account.AcctNum, 
Account.Joint, 
Applicant.PartyID,
AcctType.AcctTypeID, 
AcctType.AcctCatID, 
AcctType.AcctTypeNum, 
AcctType.AcctTypeName,
AcctType.isHSA 
FROM 
Account WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN AcctType  WITH (NOLOCK) ON Account.AcctTypeID = AcctType.AcctTypeID
INNER JOIN luAcctCat  WITH (NOLOCK) ON AcctType.AcctCatID = luAcctCat.AcctCatID
     INNER JOIN APPLICANTACCOUNT  WITH (NOLOCK) ON Account.AcctID = APPLICANTACCOUNT.AcctID
WHERE Account.AcctID = @AcctID AND APPLICANTACCOUNT.ApplID = COALESCE(@applId, APPLICANTACCOUNT.ApplID)
```

Comment: Assuming that `@applId` is a constant variable or parameter, the coalesce will be executed once (constant scan?).

Comment: The various _...ID_ fields that you are joining on - Are they primary keys?

Comment: If they are not primary keys, you should consider making them primary keys or indexes. This will give you a lot more performance gain than trying to optimize on COALESCE, especially on large tables.

Comment: In my query, all the joins columns are well indexed. I just wanted to remake the Where condition here.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is "match on appid if specified", but you have coded it in a way that means COALESCE will be called on every row for the account. If the number of rows per account is small then it won't matter. But if large, you can try this:

```
WHERE Account.AcctID = @AcctID
AND (@applId is null OR APPLICANTACCOUNT.ApplID = @applId)
```

Comment: Your piece of script doesn't replicate what Yash needs. If the @appId is null then your script will not return any row.

Comment: @Sergiu you are mistaken. The logic is fine: the `is null` test makes sure that rows are returned if the parameter is null. I can't understand why you would think this wouldn't work.

Comment: Oopsie, my bad! Sorry, didn't read carefully enough your script. But, in terms of the query plan, both queries seems to generate same query plans so there is no improvement also, Yash's script seems easier to understand at a first look (see my mistake above :) )

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out the `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` query hint in your case.

MSDN Link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx

Very interesting blog about it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature.aspx